# PHP $_GET Variable check

Tags: php, get

I have some code that checks for a value of say, var in the link.

`Http://www.blah.com/index.php?var=`

But when a link like that is sent to the server it returns a database error since var isn't set. I have tried isset (which it is set so that wont stop it) but !empty doesn't stop the var from being sent to the DB.

This is the code

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
$id = mysql_prep($_GET['id']);
....
}
```

Any help?

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: See URL: `Http://www.blah.com/index.php?var=` But you are using: `$_GET['id']` Try replace with: `$_REQUEST['var'];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;

if($id){
$id = mysql_prep($id);
....
}
```

Comment: Just `$id= intval($_GET['id']);`

Comment: why somebody will set 0 if get variable wont have the value.. what if id can have 0 value then it will screw the database

Comment: if `$id` is 0 it wont pass `if($id)`, ID = name that identifies a unique object. How can you have 0 as ID in your database @Surace?

Comment: What if 'id' isn't available, you'll get a notice.

Comment: @wes solved the undefined, simply forgot

Comment: @Krewe Mihai is correct, that will work.

Comment: im stupid, dont mind that last comment. Everything works, thanks Mihai!!

Comment: @MihaiIorga first of all naming a column ID in database wont make it unique identifier... if you talk about general convention even then id  can be 0 and be unique .... the way 1 is unique any other number is unique.... i can have -345 as unique identifier why not

Comment: @Surace That's true. However auto-incremented MySQL columns start from 1 and grow, and chances are this is the case.